# Como Puedo traer un Array que esta en uno de los registrso que tengo en mongoDB por javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mongodb, flask

Estoy trabajando en una pagina web en donde el back lo trabajo con flask y el front con Vue.

este es un registro que tengo en mi base de datos MongoDB

```
{
  "AudioNombre": "Juan",
  "AudioRuta": "/acobro/audios/ACOBRO/21-09-22/",
  "ArchicMetadata": "/acobro/audios/ACOBRO/21-09-22/Metadata.csv",
  "Estado": "evaluado",
  "Campania": "FALFLUSP -CI",
  "Cliente": "ACOBRO",
  "Fecha": "05/07/2022",
  "FechaTranscripcion": "05/07/2022",
  "HoraTranscripcion": "asd",
  "MT_DNIS": "56973330025",
  "MT_Destinatario": "Javiera Belmar",
  "MT_DireccionLLamada": "OUTBOUND",
  "MT_Ejecutivo": "Javiera Belmar",
  "MT_FechaLlamada": "05/07/2022",
  "MT_Folio": 6,
  "MT_IDScript": 2,
  "MT_MotivoMora": "no aplica",
  "MT_NombreAudio": "FALFLUSP_20220907-091021_56973330025_557_175320682-all",
  "MT_NombreScript": "Acobro_FLUJO",
  "MT_RutDestinatario": "7755339-8",
  "MT_TiempoLLamado": "adas",
  "MT_TipoLlamadaCodigo": "2",
  "MT_TipoLlamadaNombre": "Contacto Indirecto",
  "MT_UnidadNegocio": "FALFLUSP -CI",
  "TiempoAudio": 63.215935,
  "TiempoSilencio": 32.4293124,
  "Agent_spk": -1,
  "Confidence": 0.91552734,
  "TranscritoChat": [
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 7.6735134,
      "end": 8.072613,
      "transcript": "Aló."
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 9.11027,
      "end": 11.406216,
      "transcript": "Buenos días. Con la señorita Teresa O?"
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 12.702162,
      "end": 15.695404,
      "transcript": "No, De parte de quién? Javier Del Banco Fa?"
    }
  ],
  "MotivoMoraCX": "no aplica"
```

lo que necesito es sacar todos los valores del elemento TranscritoChat(el cual esta definido como un objeto dentro de MongoDB) y que lo devuelva como un Json

en el Back tengo una función que me trae el TranscritoChat pero como objeto y solo nesesito lo que este trae.
esta es la funcion que tengo en el back

```
def get(self):
        with switch_db(Transcripciones, session["dbMongoEngine"]):
            my_model = Transcripciones.objects(AudioNombre="FALRESP_20220910-125556_56953670812_485_175459783-all.mp3").fields(TranscritoChat=1, id=0)
            if my_model:
                return jsonify(my_model.to_json())
        return "Objeto no encontrado", 400
```

y me devuelve estos datos

```
"TranscritoChat": [
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 7.6735134,
      "end": 8.072613,
      "transcript": "Aló."
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 9.11027,
      "end": 11.406216,
      "transcript": "Buenos días. Con la señorita Teresa O?"
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 12.702162,
      "end": 15.695404,
      "transcript": "No, De parte de quién? Javier Del Banco Fa?"
    }
  ]
```

lo que quiero es poder sacar solamente "speaker", "start", "end", "transcript" en un Json para poder mostrarlos en el front como una lista.

Espero haber sido claro y me disculpo si omití algo importante, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Y cuál sería la estructura de ese Array que quieres tener, porque los Array no tienen claves de tipo cadena, sólo índices numéricos de la posición de cada elemento. ¿Podrías aclarar en tu pregunta cómo debería verse ese Array? Saludos

Comment: hola buenas, me disculpo por la equivocación, no era un Array sino un Json, en el cual solo estén  todos los datos de "TranscritoChat"

Comment: Pero segun lo que muestras en la pregunta ya obtuviste lo que quieres no? Dices "y me devuelve estos datos" y eso coincide casi que exactamente con lo que estás pidiendo... Entonces cual es la duda?

Comment: Es que me lo devuelve con el "TranscritoChat" y lo que quiero es que solo me devuelva el contenido de este por ejemplo en ves de esto: "TranscritoChat": [
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 7.6735134,
      "end": 8.072613,
      "transcript": "Aló."
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 9.11027,
      "end": 11.406216,
      "transcript": "Buenos días. Con la señorita Teresa O?"
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 12.702162,
      "end": 15.695404,
      "transcript": "No, De parte de quién? Javier Del Banco Fa?"
    }
  ]

Comment: Me devuelva solo esto : {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 7.6735134,
      "end": 8.072613,
      "transcript": "Aló."
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 9.11027,
      "end": 11.406216,
      "transcript": "Buenos días. Con la señorita Teresa O?"
    },
    {
      "speaker": 0,
      "start": 12.702162,
      "end": 15.695404,
      "transcript": "No, De parte de quién? Javier Del Banco Fa?"
    }

Comment: Que eso ya te lo devuelve. ¿No sabes que JSON es un formato con cierta nomenclatura? Lo que pides, es un Array. El mismo está almacenado en una clave llamada `TranscritoChat`. Si quieres sólo ese Array, de la respuesta recibida en el front basta hacer: `const soloElArray = respuesta.TranscritoChat;` o también: `const soloElArray = respuesta['TranscritoChat'];`, incluso podrías usar: `const { TranscritoChat } = respuesta;` Con eso sólo obtienes el Array. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, si quieres que el back te devuelva sólo el Array, debes acceder al campo `TranscritoChat` de la respuesta de Mongo y almacenarlo en una variable (supongo será una variable tipo `list`), y esa variable es la que vas a devolver al cliente en formato JSON. La misma será un simple Array tal como lo quieres.

Comment: Entiendo , gracias por la respuesta y la aclaración por mí falta de información